# Counting the first value from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I want to know if it's possible to count how many time a value is recorded in a array? For example, I have 2 sentences:

```
my name is marwan
and i am 20 years old
```

The first sentence contains **4 words** and the second sentence contains **6 words**.

Now I have this array:

```
$array = array(

  0 => array('1', 'value1', 'my', 'value3'),
  1 => array('1', 'value1', 'name', 'value3'),
  2 => array('1', 'value1', 'is', 'value3'),
  3 => array('1', 'value1', 'marwan', 'value3'),

  4 => array('2', 'value1', 'and', 'value3'),
  5 => array('2', 'value1', 'i', 'value3'),
  6 => array('2', 'value1', 'am', 'value3'),
  7 => array('2', 'value1', '20', 'value3'),
  8 => array('2', 'value1', 'years', 'value3'),
  9 => array('2', 'value1', 'old', 'value3')

)
```

Here, each word have its own array and the first value of the arrays are the sentence number. What I want to achieve here is to show me the total number of words in the first sentence and the second sentence through for loop. So the output should be something like:

```
Sentence '1' has '4' words:
my name is marwan

Sentence '2' has '6' words:
and i am 20 years old
```

Is something like this even possible?

Comment: Of course it's possible. You can use `array_column()` to get an array of all the sentence numbers. Then use `array_count_values()` to count the repetitions.

Comment: @Barmar could you please guide me in this? I also want the value1 and value3 of those arrays.

Comment: If you know how to program you should be able to extend the solution in the answer to get the other values from the array in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `array_reduce` to split the array into it's sentences and then simply loop over the sentences.

```
$data = array_reduce($array, function($carry, $item) {
    if (!isset($carry[$item[0]])) {
        $carry[$item[0]] = [];
    }
    $carry[$item[0]][] = $item[2];
    return $carry;
}, []);

foreach ($data as $sentence => $words) {
    echo "Sentence '$sentence' has '" .count($words) . "' words\n";
    echo join(' ', $words) . "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: In PHP it's more idiomatic to use `implode()` than `join()`.

Comment: Okay it works great so far thanks for that. But now how do I get individual values from the array? Because there are 3 values in each array and I would like to get specific values in a loop.

Comment: @Philipp is there anywhere I can talk to you through chat? It’s really hard over here.